# Puppeteer snapshot concatenate different snapshot of my page into one

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to basically take a snapshot of my website and puppeteer seems to take snapshots where different screens are concatenated. So even the width of the 2 snapshot to compare is far from being the same:

[image: different size of snapshot]

Here's an example of the snapshot returned. The width of it change each time I do the test:

[image]

What's going on ? Is there multiple snapshot by default, is it a cinematic? I don't see the option.